# Negation of a chain of verbs conjoined with "and"

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, negation

Let's consider the following sentence:

> Ducks are things that *walk* like ducks and *quack* like ducks.

Now, I wanna negate it to describe something that is *not* a duck. The most verbose way to do it might probably be something like:

> Dogs are things that *do not walk* like ducks ***and** do not quack* like ducks.

While this seems to be grammatically correct to me, the repetition of `does not` makes this sentence rather crude. I would like something a bit more concise. My attempt to achieve this could result in something like this:

> Dogs are things that *do not walk **and** quack* like ducks.

Now I'm not so sure what my phrase actually means. That the dogs do not walk *at all* but *do* quack like ducks? That the dogs do not walk *like ducks* but *do* quack like ducks? Or, maybe, it actually means what I wanted it to mean: that neither dogs walk like ducks nor they quack like them.

Okay. Maybe I should view this sentence from the position of the formal mathematical logic. What we have here is an *A & B* construct (walking & quacking), and I'm trying to apply negation to it: *!(A & B)*. Mathematical logic suggests that *!(A & B)* is equal to *!A | !B*, that is, *not A **or** not B*. So maybe I should switch to a different conjunction? Let's try that:

> Dogs are things that *do not walk **or** quack* like ducks.

Did that help? Or maybe it made everything even worse? I'm totally confused. Please help me find a balance between being not overly verbose and keeping what I try to say clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

Dogs neither walk nor quack like ducks.

Comment: *Rocks neither eat nor shine like stars.* Using your suggestion, is the reader intended to assume that stars eat?

Comment: Of course [stars eat](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/48746034/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/giant-dying-star-caught-devouring-alien-planet/). (-:

Comment: In my attempt to avoid using *walk* in my counterexample, I have inadvertently stumbled upon hungry stars. -_- *Rocks neither walk nor shine likes stars.* ... unless you're going to tell me that stars walk, too!

Comment: @PeterShor I was expecting your link to go to a story about Lindsay Lohan’s eating disorders or something like that …

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with the level of verbosity of

> Ducks *walk* like ducks and *quack* like ducks.

then, IMO, you are bound to be happy with the level of verbosity of

> Dogs neither *walk* like ducks nor *quack* like ducks.

But if, on the other hand, you do not mind the (potential) ambiguity of

> Ducks *walk* and *quack* like ducks.

then, of course, neither will you mind the (potential) ambiguity of

> Dogs neither *walk* nor *quack* like ducks.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the more succinct sentences that you propose suffer from ambiguity.

> Dogs are things that do not walk and quack like ducks.

From this, one could read:

- Dogs do not walk; and
- Dogs quack like ducks.

> Dogs are things that do not walk or quack like ducks.

From this, one could read:

- Dogs do not walk; or
- Dogs quack like ducks; or
- Dogs are afflicted with both conditions.

Because both misinterpretations have trouble linking *do not walk* with *like ducks*, duplicating *like ducks* adds clarity. Additionally, if you use *nor*, the reader will read the negation through to the second term.

> Dogs are things that do not walk like ducks nor quack like ducks.

Alternatively, since *quacking* is something that (generally) only ducks do, you could reverse the order and help the reader, even without removing all ambiguity entirely. You'll still want *nor* to ensure the negation commutes.

> Dogs are things that do not quack nor walk like ducks.

If you wanted to break the rules of grammar and lean more towards mathematical description (as I often like to do), you could use parentheses to eliminate ambiguity:

> Dogs are things that do not (walk or quack) like ducks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently, not much can be done to shorten the initial variant I proposed. Still, solution using _nor_ does look slightly more elegant. I also know that quacking is a trait that belongs to ducks rather exclusively. It was simply a form of a reference joke, maybe not a very good one =).

Comment: Driveby downvotes are helpful. </sarcasm>

Comment: I'm trying to decide whether the sentence *"Dogs are things that do not walk or quack like ducks"* would ever be interpreted this way by a native English speaker. If it would, then you would have to conclude that switching the order of the pieces joined by *"or"* gives a reasonable English sentence. But *"Dogs are things that quack like ducks or do not walk,"* sounds really off to me.

Comment: @PeterShor It only sounds off to you because you know that dogs walk. This was an example sentence intended to demonstrate the ambiguity and ask for help. Here's a different example: "Criminals don't get caught or go to jail." This should help you understand why there is ambiguity.

Comment: @Ian: but that does that mean *"criminals either don't get caught or else they go to jail"* or *"criminals neither get caught nor go to jail"*? I would interpret that as unambiguously having the second meaning, while to be parallel with your duck sentence, it needs to have the first meaning.

Comment: @PeterShor EXACTLY. Ambiguity, my friend.